# Review process for the Messenger App without setting up a test user account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot, social-media, facebook-app-requests, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am in the process of developing an app that necessitates certain permissions from users, specifically: `whatsapp_business_messaging`, `pages_manage_metadata`, and `pages_messaging`.

For my app to function correctly, it needs three types of verifications:

1. Business Verification
2. Access Verification (Tech Provider)
3. App Review

Currently, I've secured both Business and Access Verifications. However, I'm yet to undergo the App Review process.

Could you provide some clarity on the prerequisites for the App Review?

I'm also encountering a challenge. As part of the review process, I need to create a test user for the reviewer to evaluate the functionality of my code. But when I attempt to create a test user, I'm met with the error: "The ability to create test users is disabled temporarily." Without the ability to set up a test user, I'm uncertain how to move forward with submitting my app for review.

Would you be able to assist me in resolving this matter?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Is there an alternative to the app review process that doesn't involve creating a test user account? If not, how can I gain user permission without verifying the app?